# how to avoid unset http_proxy everytime I launch Postman? I am under a proxy

Tags: proxy, postman

Everytime I launch Postman need to unset http_proxy manually, I am aware that a common settings should be applied

Comment: Perhaps by using some command line magic ? https://github.com/postmanlabs/newman/blob/develop/README.md#configuring-proxy

Comment: thanks actually unset http_proxy, unset https_proxy works, thanks